# saving information in a database/displaying them in a GUI window. (Visual Studios)

Tags: c#, sql, visual-studio, visual-studio-2012

I am trying to make a room request program and have two windows that I need to connect to the database (which I know how to do). The two windows are called EMERGENCY and JANITOR. My issue is I don't know how to store information in a database. Like let's say someone logs in as EMERGENCY and sends a request, the information needs to be stored and once the JANITOR logs in, he can see the requests. So far I have the database but not sure about storing information in it without manually adding them. If anyone has any guides or links on how to do this, I'd appreciate it!

EMERGENCY window code:

```css
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using System.Data.SqlClient;

namespace LOGINPAGE
{
    public partial class EMERGENCY : Form
    {
        

        public EMERGENCY()
        {

            InitializeComponent();
        }

        void Fillcombo()
        {

        }

        private void EMERGENCY_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
// TODO: This line of code loads data into the 'roomInfoDataSet6.Table' table. You can move, or remove it, as needed.

        
        }

        private void xButton1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            this.Close();
            Application.Exit();
        }

        private void xButton2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

        }

        private void comboBox1_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

        }

        private void Search_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

        }

    }

}
```

JANITOR code:

```css
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace LOGINPAGE
{
    public partial class JANITOR : Form
    {
        public JANITOR()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void label1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

        }

        private void dataGridView1_CellContentClick(object sender, DataGridViewCellEventArgs e)
        {

        }

        private void JANITOR_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            // TODO: This line of code loads data into the 'roomInfoDataSet3.Table' table. You can move, or remove it, as needed.
            this.tableTableAdapter.Fill(this.roomInfoDataSet3.Table);

        }

        private void xButton4_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

        }

        private void xButton2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            this.Close();
            Application.Exit();
        }
    }
}
```

[EMERGENCY](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xsYpm.png)

[JANITOR](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Hqnx3.png)

Comment: You can start by learning the basic of Entity Framework https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Z7713GBhi4k

Comment: That's too complex than what's needed....

Comment: I think it the opposite, Entity framework , Linq to SQL are built to make developer life easier, other wise you can find other things in google using sqlConnection and other classes to manage your connection and you will copy and past the code (woow it working) but it not a professional way or the right way to do it. you can look how to use DataSet if you want but my advice what ever way you chose (you don't have to write much code) because this is the role of visual studio not us lol.

Comment: As this is a college project, we are only allowed to use SqlConnection. If you have any knowledge of using sql, I would love to heart it. Thanks

Comment: Em , okay cool, and sorry I didn't know that, see this link maybe it can help you .http://dotnetdaily.net/tutorials/ado-net-tutorial-create-update-delete-operations/

Comment: “So far I have the database”. There are many different databases and RDBMSs with different ways to use each one. You need to tell us which database you are using.

Comment: local sql database

Answer (score 0):

You can use Ms access db

You will find connecting to acess from c# to really easy with lots of YouTube video tutorials

I can have a table in it database that is updated by a "save emergency" button and a load emergency  button by the janitor will just populate a datagridview with items from the same table filled with the first button

Comment: That would work for my needs. Any code/examples on how to do this?

Comment: You can start learning here http://www.google.com.ng/url?q=http://m.youtube.com/watch%3Fv%3DWDxNNj4cjMA&sa=U&ved=0ahUKEwivotGKq47MAhVB6xQKHYkLALwQFggRMAA&usg=AFQjCNHvDQsuEfXdsz0GR9t9SFRwOC_x2Q

Comment: What database type? Access? Mysql? What version of either? In anycase you'll need just one table. Give me details of the db I'll walk you through the process. And please accept answer.

Comment: I'm using a local database in visual studios

Comment: I'm not sure what you are asking. It's a local sql database.

Comment: I haven't accepted your answer because you haven't really done anything but tell me to go to youtube. If you can show some code/examples I might've accepted.....